# Memory Allocation of char** array in C

Tags: c

I am writing a basic shell program in C for an assignment. I am currently having troubles allocating the memory that will be used to store the command line arguments that will be passed into the program to be parsed.

I am getting a segmentation fault if the input size is greater than or equal to 4 (i.e. "this is a test" will produce a segmentation fault upon program terminations whereas "this is a" will not).

I imagine my issue lies within how I was allocating the memory but the program is capturing each token that I enter and printing them to the screen.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  char cap[] = "";
  char* cmd;

  const int MAX_ARGS = 16;
  const int MAX_ARG_SIZE = 256;
  char** arglst = (char**)malloc(MAX_ARGS * sizeof(char*));
  for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ARGS; i++)
  {
    arglst[i] = (char*)malloc(MAX_ARG_SIZE * sizeof(char));
  }

  pid_t cpid;
  //implement ls, cd, mkdir, chdir, rm, rmdir
  while(1)
  {
    printf("Enter a command: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", cap);

    int index = 0;
    cmd = strtok(cap, " ");
    while( cmd != NULL )
    {
      strcpy(arglst[index], cmd);
      cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
      index++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
      printf("%s\n", arglst[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", index);

    /*
    if(strcmp(cap, "quit") == 0) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    if( (cpid = fork()) == -1) perror("fork()");
    else if(cpid == 0)
    {
      if( execvp(cmd, arglst) == -1 )
      {
        errorp("cmd error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
      cpid = wait(NULL);
      strcpy(cmd, "/bin/");
    }
    */
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
      free(arglst[i]);
    }
    free(arglst);
    return 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you should add in 1 to the size final of malloc and add "'\0' to your string to indicate  end of stream it.

Comment: `char cap[] = "";` That is a 1 character array. Arrays do not automatically grow in size. Writing any more than an empty string into it later as you do with `scanf` causes a buffer overflow and undefined behaviour.

Comment: Fix also the scan format string: you have an 's' too much.

Comment: `char**` is a pointer, not an array. It looks like you want to use a 2D array which is not what you allocate. In fact a single allocation would be sufficient for this. There are many dupes about what you are doing and some also provide information how to do what you really want.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Still this has been asked and solved wrongly and sometimes corrected in comments and answers so many times here. Closing as a dupe is certainly much more helpful than just stating the code behaves correctly (what any code does unless there is a bug in the language implementation. And while asking for X, Y definitively is allocation of a 2D array which is a single `malloc`.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Did I state different? This is apparently an XY problem, OP wants to use a 2D array and confuses these jagged arrays for them. Unfortunately this is a common problem, mostly with teachers who have not kept up with modern C from the 80ies.

Comment: This question was closed for the _wrong_ reason. The issues with this program are _not_ merely typos. There are at least 8 bugs [that I fixed] beyond any "will not compile" (e.g. `errorp` -> `perror`) issue. The question is complete and is answerable.

Comment: @AdrianMole Of course. OP commented it out because it would segfault because `cmd` is used and is NULL at that point. Using a pre-alloc on `arglst[i]` is bad--one of the elements has to get NULL to work with `execvp`. I have working restructured code with full bug annotations waiting. Nitpicking on the single issue OP mentioned would just add to the clutter (e.g. OP fixes the immediate bug and has to post a new question). This is the 2nd time I've seen one of the closers [_not_ you] here jump the gun and close an answerable question [within minutes of my posting an answer]

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you! (And, I welcome scrutiny ;-) Now, we just need one more kindly soul to complete the reopen. On the other question I mentioned I had to send the fix to OP via email because the question also got deleted. Here, if the question isn't reopened [eventually], I'll [reluctantly] post the code to my pastebin account with a link in the comments here.

Comment: Aarggh! Once again, what is up with the superfluous/erroneous close of this question? This second time is for being a duplicate of the linked question!?!? This question is absolutely _not_ a duplicate. There are many more issues here that the link did _not_ address. In fact, the link isn't even a very good question/answer--it does not provide a way to learn 2D allocation [which is _not_ the issue here] but merely validates one code snippet with a single approach.

Comment: @CraigEstey Well, as the OP has 'accepted' the proposed duplicate (that's what the "Community♦" close-vote represents), then I'm not sure what else we can do - other than raising the issue on Meta.SO. The 'duplicate' most certainly won't help the OP fix their code, and that should be clear from both your comments and your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of bugs.

This won't compile (e.g. `errorp` instead of `perror`).

`cap` is too small to contain a line. Better to use (e.g.) `char cap[1000];`

Doing a preallocate of each `arglst[i]` *once* before the main loop is problematic. One of the cells has to get a `NULL` value so it works with `execvp`. However, doing so would cause a memory leak. The solution is to use `strdup` inside the `strtok` loop so that cells are only allocated when needed.

Also, because `arglst[i]` is set only *once* during initialization, doing a loop with `free` near the bottom causes UB [accessing the buffer after being freed]. This is fixed with the use of `strdup` below.

The commented out code references variables (e.g. `cmd` and `cap`) that should not be relied upon. At that point, `cmd` will be `NULL`, causing a segfault.

The `return 0;` is placed incorrectly. Only one iteration (and thus only one command) will be executed.

The final free of `arglst` (e.g. `free(arglst)`) is done *inside* the outer loop, so referencing it on the second iteration is UB.

There are a few more issues [annotated below]

---

Here's a refactored version. It fixes the bugs and is heavily annotated.

I've used the preprocessor to show old/original code vs new/fixed code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

Likewise, using `#if 1` for purely new code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#if 1
#include <sys/wait.h>
#endif

int
main(void)
{
// NOTE/BUG: this must be large enough to contain a command line
#if 0
    char cap[] = "";
#else
    char cap[1000];
#endif
    char *cmd;

    const int MAX_ARGS = 16;
    char **arglst = malloc(MAX_ARGS * sizeof(*arglst));

// NOTE/BUG: because we need to add a NULL terminator, don't preallocate the
// elements -- we'll leak memory
#if 0
    const int MAX_ARG_SIZE = 256;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARGS; i++) {
        arglst[i] = (char *) malloc(MAX_ARG_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    }
#endif

    pid_t cpid;

    // implement ls, cd, mkdir, chdir, rm, rmdir
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a command: ");
// NOTE/BUG: this didn't work too well
#if 0
        scanf("%[^\n]s", cap);
#else
        fgets(cap,sizeof(cap),stdin);
        cap[strcspn(cap,"\n")] = 0;
#endif

        int index = 0;

        cmd = strtok(cap, " ");
        while (cmd != NULL) {
// NOTE/BUG: we should strdup dynamically rather than preallocate -- otherwise,
// we leak memory when we set the necessary NULL pointer below
#if 0
            strcpy(arglst[index], cmd);
#else
            arglst[index] = strdup(cmd);
#endif
            cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
            index++;
        }

// NOTE/FIX: we have to add a NULL terminator before passing to execvp
#if 1
        arglst[index] = NULL;
#endif

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", arglst[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", index);

// NOTE/BUG: we can't [shouldn't] rely on cap here
#if 0
        if (strcmp(cap, "quit") == 0)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
#else
        if (strcmp(arglst[0], "quit") == 0)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
#endif

        if ((cpid = fork()) == -1)
            perror("fork()");
        else if (cpid == 0) {
// NOTE/BUG: cmd will be NULL here
#if 0
            if (execvp(cmd, arglst) == -1) {
                errorp("cmd error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
#else
            if (execvp(arglst[0], arglst) == -1) {
                perror("cmd error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
#endif
// NOTE/BUG: this will never be executed
#if 0
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
#endif
        }
        else {
            cpid = wait(NULL);
// NOTE/BUG -- cmd is NULL and this serves no purpose
#if 0
            strcpy(cmd, "/bin/");
#endif
        }

// NOTE/BUG: in the _old_ code that did a single preallocate of these cells
// _before_ the loop, freeing them here is wrong -- they would never be
// reallocated because -- the fix using strdup alleviates the issue
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            free(arglst[i]);
        }

// NOTE/BUG: freeing this is wrong because we do the allocation only _once_
// above the outer loop
#if 0
        free(arglst);
#endif

// NOTE/BUG -- this should be placed at the end to allow multiple commands --
// here it stops after the first command is input
#if 0
        return 0;
#endif
    }

// NOTE/FIX: correct placement for the above
#if 1
    free(arglst);

    return 0;
#endif
}
```

---

Here's that version cleaned up so that only the fixed code remains:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char cap[1000];
    char *cmd;

    const int MAX_ARGS = 16;
    char **arglst = malloc(MAX_ARGS * sizeof(*arglst));

    pid_t cpid;

    // implement ls, cd, mkdir, chdir, rm, rmdir
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a command: ");
        fgets(cap,sizeof(cap),stdin);
        cap[strcspn(cap,"\n")] = 0;

        int index = 0;

        cmd = strtok(cap, " ");
        while (cmd != NULL) {
            arglst[index] = strdup(cmd);
            cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
            index++;
        }

        arglst[index] = NULL;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", arglst[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", index);

        if (strcmp(arglst[0], "quit") == 0)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        if ((cpid = fork()) == -1)
            perror("fork()");
        else if (cpid == 0) {
            if (execvp(arglst[0], arglst) == -1) {
                perror("cmd error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else {
            cpid = wait(NULL);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            free(arglst[i]);
        }
    }

    free(arglst);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that the above does *not* check for the number of actual arguments exceeding `MAX_ARGS`.

While we *could* add that check, a better way is to use `realloc` on `arglst` to dynamically increase it, so an arbitrary limit on the number of arguments isn't needed

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char cap[1000];
    char *cmd;

    char **arglst = NULL;
    int argmax = 0;

    pid_t cpid;

    // implement ls, cd, mkdir, chdir, rm, rmdir
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a command: ");
        fgets(cap,sizeof(cap),stdin);
        cap[strcspn(cap,"\n")] = 0;

        int index = 0;

        cmd = strtok(cap, " ");
        while (cmd != NULL) {
            if (index >= argmax) {
                argmax += 10;
                arglst = realloc(arglst,sizeof(*arglst) * (argmax + 1));
            }

            arglst[index] = strdup(cmd);
            cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");

            index++;
        }

        arglst[index] = NULL;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", arglst[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", index);

        if (strcmp(arglst[0], "quit") == 0)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        if ((cpid = fork()) == -1)
            perror("fork()");
        else if (cpid == 0) {
            if (execvp(arglst[0], arglst) == -1) {
                perror("cmd error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else {
            cpid = wait(NULL);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            free(arglst[i]);
        }
    }

    free(arglst);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The original code used `malloc` and/or `strdup` on the individual elements of `arglst` (e.g. `arglst[i]`).

This makes the code general enough to be used in more complex scenarios. But, as the code is written, the `malloc/strdup` for the individual elements really isn't necessary.

This is because the cells are fully used [up] at the bottom of the main loop, so we don't *need* to save them.

We can *reuse* the `cap` buffer space on each loop iteration because we do *not* need any tokens to live on iteration to iteration.

We can simply store the return value from `strtok` and simplify the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char cap[1000];
    char *cmd;

    char **arglst = NULL;
    int argmax = 0;

    pid_t cpid;

    // implement ls, cd, mkdir, chdir, rm, rmdir
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a command: ");
        fgets(cap,sizeof(cap),stdin);
        cap[strcspn(cap,"\n")] = 0;

        int index = 0;

        cmd = strtok(cap, " ");
        while (cmd != NULL) {
            if (index >= argmax) {
                argmax += 10;
                arglst = realloc(arglst,sizeof(*arglst) * (argmax + 1));
            }

            arglst[index] = cmd;
            cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");

            index++;
        }

        arglst[index] = NULL;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", arglst[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", index);

        if (strcmp(arglst[0], "quit") == 0)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        if ((cpid = fork()) == -1)
            perror("fork()");
        else if (cpid == 0) {
            if (execvp(arglst[0], arglst) == -1) {
                perror("cmd error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else {
            cpid = wait(NULL);
        }
    }

    free(arglst);

    return 0;
}
```